# Ignoring errors when deserializing a specific property whose type may not be able to be resolved

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm serializing a type that has an `object` property, like this:

```
class MyData
{
    ... various properties ...
    object UserProp;
}
```

Since I'm using `TypeNameHandling.Auto`, deserialization works pretty well, *provided the deserializer has access to the same assemblies*. If the deserializer doesn't have access to the assembly containing the actual value of `UserProp`, I get a `JsonSerializationException`.

I would like to change that behavior a bit. I would like to try and deserialize the UserProp property, and if it fails - do something. Maybe raise an exception, maybe set the deserialized value to null.

How can I tell JSON.NET to use custom code when deserializing a specific property? I can't use a `JsonConverter`, because I don't know the actual type of `UserProp`.

Example: 
On the serialization side I have this code:

```
private class MyContext { ... }
var data = new MyData { UserProp = new MyContext(); }
```

The deserialization fails claiming it can't create the MyContext class (which is correct, because MyContext is a private class in another assembly). I want the deserialization not to fail, but rather put null in the property.

Comment: Why do you need to know the actual type of `UserProp` to use `JsonConverter`?

Comment: I don't. I thought it would help solve this issue, but it doesn't.

Comment: What makes it fail? I don't see any constraint on this, could explain the problem with it?

Comment: @zmbq It is possible to use a JsonConverter for this.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell JSON.NET to use custom code when deserializing a specific property?

Use a `JsonConverter`.  This is precisely what they were designed for.

> I can't use a JsonConverter, because I don't know the actual type of UserProp.

Your assumption is incorrect.  You do not need to know the type of an object ahead of time to make a converter for it.

Below is a `JsonConverter` that will do what you want.  It works by loading the unknown part of the JSON into a `JObject`, reading the `$type` property from the `JObject` and then attempting to resolve the type name into an actual `Type`.  If successful, it uses `ToObject()` to convert the `JObject` to an instance of that type.  Otherwise, it simply returns null.  If any exception is thrown during this process, the converter eats the exception and returns null.

Here is the code:

```
class UnknownObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            string typeName = (string)jo["$type"];
            Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
            if (type != null)
            {
                return jo.ToObject(type, serializer);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use this converter, just add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your `UserProp` property like this:

```
class MyData
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnknownObjectConverter))]
    public object UserProp { get; set; }
}
```

A note for consideration: I have found that in some cases, `GetType()` will not be able to resolve a type from an external assembly unless the type name uses the "full" assembly name format.  For that reason you might want to set the `TypeNameAssemblyFormat` setting to `FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full` when you serialize.

Below is a demo I put together to test the converter.  For purposes of demonstration, I added some extra properties to your `MyData` class.  You'll notice that there are now two properties of type `object`, `UserProp` and `UserProp2`, both of which use the `UnknownObjectConverter`.  I created some JSON such that `UserProp` will resolve to the known type `System.Tuple<string>` whereas `UserProp2` refers to a type that doesn't exist.  As you can see from the output, all the properties are deserialized correctly, except of course `UserProp2`, which is null.

```
class MyData
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnknownObjectConverter))]
    public object UserProp { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnknownObjectConverter))]
    public object UserProp2 { get; set; }

    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""Foo"": ""fizz"",
            ""UserProp"": {
                ""$type"": ""System.Tuple`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"",
                ""Item1"": ""pow""
            },
            ""UserProp2"": {
                ""$type"": ""JsonTest.Something, JsonTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"",
                ""Baz"": ""whiff""
            },
            ""Bar"": ""bang""
        }";

        MyData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Foo);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Bar);
        Console.WriteLine(((Tuple<string>)data.UserProp).Item1);
        Console.WriteLine(data.UserProp2 == null ? "null" : data.UserProp2.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fizz
bang
pow
null
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution, but it's ugly. I've marked the `UserProp` property as non-serialized, and added a `string _jsonUserProp` that is serialized prior to the serialization of the entire object.

On the other side, I deserialize the object, getting a JSON string in `_jsonUserProp`, and I then deserialize it. If I get the exception I set it to null.

This works, but again - it's ugly.